# RegEx - Python: Error:TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: python, regex, string, typeerror, findall

I need to write an RegEx to search for invoice numbers (example: 513426 / 41811 / MIU ).
but i always get the error:

```
 "Python: Error:TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string' "
```

Do you know what I did wrong
[image]

I would really be thankful for any kind of help.

Many thanks

Milena

Comment: You need to include the string you are searching with the regex. `re.findall(pattern, string)`

Comment: You didn't give the regex input data. You gave it the pattern, but no string containing the invoice numbers.

Answer (score -1):

This is a usage of findall, you have to provide the string where you want to search the regex.

```
m=re.findall(regex,target_string)
```